Python: Having trouble Copying Numbering Format and Saving it to Excel
I am able to get a script to copy over things from a Word Doc. However, I am having trouble copying over the numbering format(Match Destination Formatting) which I need. My code is below, if anyone can help me that would be great :)
import os
from docx import Document
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def read_word_doc(file_path):
    doc = Document(file_path)
    content = ""
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        content += paragraph.text + "\n"
    return content
def copy_to_excel(ws, content, row):
    for paragraph in content.split("\n"):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=paragraph)
        row+=1
    return row
def create_excel_file(folder_path, excel_file_name):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    files = os.listdir(r"C:\folder")
    row = 1
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith(".DOCX"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            content = read_word_doc(file_path)
            row = copy_to_excel(ws, content, row)
wb.save(path)

Tried using library that interact with Windows but that was really buggy. Tried Pandas but that was also no help.

What number formatting are you trying to copy? From a table or something else?

The Python libraries docx and openpyxl are great for reading and writing Word and Excel files respectively. However, they have limitations when it comes to handling complex formatting such as the numbering format in Word documents.
The docx library does not support reading the numbering format from a Word document. It only reads the text content of the document. Similarly, the openpyxl library does not support writing the numbering format to an Excel file. It only writes plain text.
If you need to preserve the numbering format when copying content from a Word document to an Excel file, you might need to use a different approach. One possible approach is to use a library that interacts with the Microsoft Office applications themselves, such as pywin32 (also known as win32com.client). This library allows you to automate the Office applications, which means you can perform tasks that require preserving complex formatting.
However, please note that pywin32 only works on Windows and it requires the Office applications to be installed on the machine where the script is running.
I'm sorry but I don't have much experence with pywin32 or the like, so I can't provide you code samples. But hopefully this helps. I would have a look at some tutorials on pywin32 to work out how to do it. This might give you a start.

Openpyxl, does support writing the numbering format and other formatting to an Excel file, as in write a value to a cell and set the formatting like `number_format' for that cell. I think you are referring to Openpyxl can only write the plain text because you cannot obtain the format from the Word Doc, but that is unclear

Yes you are right, sorry for being unclear. I shall update my answer.

Yeah that was unfortunately the library that I used that was buggy and it made the formatting worst. The format seem to have only pasted the values instead of the keeping the format that was originally in excel.

@ConnorDavidson Tried this and the reason why I have trouble with this is because it doesn't paste matching destination formatting.
